# How do I use an enum declared in a class in that same class's base's template

Tags: c++, c++11

Sorry for the wordy/overlong question, but I don't know how else to word this.

I have a class. This class extends a base class that is templated. I want to use an enum that is declared in the derived class as one of the template arguments. Not a value from it, the actual enum, although I doubt this makes a difference. If I try to do it, I get a C2065 undeclared identifier error, such as in this simplified example.

```
template<class Value>
class Base
{
 public:
    Value foo;
}

class Derived : public Base<Derived::Colors>
{
    enum Colors
    {
        blue,
        red,
    }
}
```

I've tried looking around, and found that enums are not forward-declarable if they are inside a class, so I don't quite know what to do. It seems like a pretty big oversight to leave such a use case unsupported, so is there a way to do it? In my actual code, I'd rather keep this enum in my class as it is closely tied to its functionality.

Comment: Must the enum be nested in the derived class?

Comment: Yes, that's part of the question.

Comment: @ProgramGamer: But the question is *why* does it have to be? There's nothing to gain by restricting yourself in such a way. Especially with strong enums.

Comment: It's mainly namespace pollution that I'd like to avoid. I don't want a bunch of class specific enums to bleed into the outer or even global namespace.

Comment: Put the enum and the class in its own namespace (Making sure that the enum is before the class). Otherwise, there is no way the compiler can use Colors before it is defined as it is an incomplete type.

Comment: This sounds like a design problem. Base classes should not depend on details of derived classes.

Comment: If `Base`'s template will always be an enum, you could make `foo` to be type `int` and do away with the template entirely.

Comment: It might not be an enum. In my actual code, I'm using it as the key to an unordered map, which could be anything, and strings in particular are quite useful for this sort of thing.

Comment: I admittedly was hoping that some weird feature of C++ would allow me to forward declare an enum nested in a class for the specific purpose of using it as a template argument, but if that's impossible, I'll answer my own question and mark it as solved for whoever finds this in the future. I'll wait a bit more in the hopes that someone has an answer, but it doesn't look likely.

Answer (score 0):

So, as it turns out, it is impossible, at least with C++11, to do this. One would need to do something similar to this:

```
template<class Value>
class Base
{
 public:
    Value foo;
}

// Does not compile
enum Derived::Colors;

class Derived : public Base<Derived::Colors>
{
    enum Colors
    {
        blue,
        red,
    }
}
```

for `Colors` to be known before adding it as a template argument. However, this is impossible due to the way forward declaration works with enums. Basically, if they are declared inside of a class, they are explicitly disallowed by the standard to be forward declared outside of that class.

Comment: You could always just define an `enum DerivedColors` outside the class, and write `using Colors = DerivedColors;` inside.